# I am stuck with making a connection of AWS Elastic Beanstalk and RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I've been struggling here to connect my Tomcat AWS Elastic Beanstalk and RDS.

I've successfully launched a TOMCAT server and add RDS to it by following the instructions.

But I have no idea how to connect my tomcat server to added RDS server.

[Connecting to a Database (Tomcat Platforms)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html#java-rds-tomcat)

You will see Connecting to a Database (Tomcat Platforms). But I have no idea how and where to put the example source code.

So I just made a Test project with example JSP code at guide, built the project, and deployed to my Tomcat server.

But it doesn't work either showing the message:

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /main.jsp at line 24
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /main.jsp at line 24

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /main.jsp at line 24

21:     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
22:     System.out.println("Driver loaded!");
23:   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
24:     throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", e);
25:   }
26: 
27:   Connection conn = null;


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:579)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find the driver in the classpath!
    org.apache.jsp.main_jsp._jspService(main_jsp.java:134)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1335)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1163)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:125)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:62)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    org.apache.jsp.main_jsp._jspService(main_jsp.java:131)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.50 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.50
```

Could you guys just help me out? I've spent all my day but couldn't solve it yet.

Comment: Add the complete stack trace, that may shed some light on whats happening.

Comment: @Yogesh_D Hey, I just added more error messages. I used the same source code as AWS guide instruction https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html#java-rds-tomcat

Comment: your missing `oracle jdbc jar`, see `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

Comment: @RedBoy How can I install jdbc driver in my EC-2 server? Should I download Oracle DBMS and install?

Comment: Simple download from `oracle.com` either locally or directly on EC-2.

Comment: @RedBoy Is this normal? Whenever I launch a new Tomcat BeanStalk instance, do i have to download and install jdbc?

Comment: No, I feel you should Oracle jar with your app war. If you are using maven, you could include it to your package phase.

Comment: @RedBoy Thanks, I followed your instruction and had a progress. But stuck with another issue. Might be a big help if you could take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015707/aws-beanstalk-doesnt-tend-to-connect-to-aws-rds