# AWS BeanStalk doesn't tend to connect to AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle11g, connection, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I think I am almost there.

I created an instance of AWS BeanStalk and added an oracle DB instance to it.

When I found the log, I saw the driver was loaded but it keeps saying that URL is 
 invalid.

Here are my RDS info and log message.

[RDS Info] 
Endpoint = aa1c9autjaqoufk.c2k1ch01futy.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com
Port = 1521
Public Access = yes

[System Log]

```
25-Jun-2018 02:42:56.759 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Jun-2018 02:42:56.787 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
25-Jun-2018 02:42:56.796 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
25-Jun-2018 02:42:56.799 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
25-Jun-2018 02:42:56.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1366 ms
25-Jun-2018 02:42:56.842 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
25-Jun-2018 02:42:56.848 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.50
25-Jun-2018 02:42:56.872 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
25-Jun-2018 02:42:58.613 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
25-Jun-2018 02:42:58.689 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT has finished in 1,817 ms
25-Jun-2018 02:42:58.693 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Jun-2018 02:42:58.720 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
25-Jun-2018 02:42:58.736 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1935 ms
Loading driver...
Driver loaded!
jdbc:oracle:oci://aa1c9autjaqoufk.c2k1ch01futy.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/ebdb?user=username&password=password
SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified
SQLState: 99999
VendorError: 17067
Closing the connection.
SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified
SQLState: 99999
VendorError: 17067
Closing the connection.
```

I included ojdbc8 drvier in my web project library and made a build.
Is this about driver? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Message clearly says your URL is incorrect,

It should be something like below.

`//step1 load the driver class

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");`

`//step2 create  the connection object

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(

"jdbc:oracle:thin:@aa1c9autjaqoufk.c2k1ch01futy.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:1521:edb","username","password");`
 `

Comment: What you meant by amazon-rds-urlt is endpoint right? I assure that I input the right URL

Comment: @KimHyungJune Yes I meant `amazon-rds-url` refer below for step by step example. https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/